# SQL sub-select query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am attempting to query the hotel database to find the total cost of a booking. I am using a sub-select query however I am constantly receiving an error.

This is the query, I want it to display the booking id and room number along with total cost.

```
    SELECT BOOKING_ID, ROOM_NO , SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL FROM
    (
        SELECT (END_DATE-START_DATE) DAYDIFF, ((END_DATE-START_DATE)*ROOM_PRICE) TOTAL_ROOM 
        FROM ROOM_TBL NATURAL JOIN ROOM_DETAILS_TBL WHERE BOOKING_ID = &BOOKING_ID
    )  FROM ROOM_TBL;
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: too many FROMs up there, remove the one after the last )

Comment: The thing I love about Oracle is it turns any error into a `missing parenthesis` error.  I'm pretty sure if you run out of disk space, you'll get `missing parenthesis`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have a few issues.

First, you have two `FROM`s in the query one before the subquery and one after the subquery.

Second, you have no `GROUP BY` but you have an aggregate function being used.

It seem like you might want:

```
SELECT BOOKING_ID, ROOM_NO , SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL 
FROM
(
    SELECT BOOKING_ID, 
        ROOM_NO, 
        (END_DATE-START_DATE) DAYDIFF, 
        ((END_DATE-START_DATE)*ROOM_PRICE) TOTAL 
    FROM ROOM_TBL 
    NATURAL JOIN ROOM_DETAILS_TBL 
    WHERE BOOKING_ID = &BOOKING_ID
)  
GROUP BY BOOKING_ID, ROOM_NO;
```

Edit, if you want a `TOTAL` row, then you can use `GROUP BY ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT max(BOOKING_ID) Booking_id, 
  case when ROOM_NO is null then ' ' else room_no end Room_no, 
  SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL 
FROM
(
    SELECT BOOKING_ID, 
        ROOM_NO, 
        (END_DATE-START_DATE) DAYDIFF, 
        ((END_DATE-START_DATE)*ROOM_PRICE) TOTAL 
    FROM ROOM_TBL 
    NATURAL JOIN ROOM_DETAILS_TBL 
    WHERE BOOKING_ID = &BOOKING_ID
)  
GROUP BY ROLLUP (room_no);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ec0a/13)

If you want the data in a column, then you can use a Common Table Expression on the subquery:

```
with cte as
(
     SELECT BOOKING_ID, 
        ROOM_NO, 
        (END_DATE-START_DATE) DAYDIFF, 
        ((END_DATE-START_DATE)*ROOM_PRICE) TOTAL 
    FROM ROOM_TBL 
    NATURAL JOIN ROOM_DETAILS_TBL 
 )
 select booking_id,
    room_no,
    total,
    case when rn = 1 then totalbooking else null end totalbooking     
 from
 (
     select booking_id,
        room_no,
        total,
        (select sum(total) from cte) TotalBooking,
        row_number() over(partition by booking_id order by room_no) rn
     from cte
 )
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ec0a/14)

Comment: A bit of unsolicited advice: make sure you limit `ROOM_TBL.START_DATE` and `ROOM_TBL.END_DATE` to date only (no time component) or you'll get some very weird results. Don't trust other programmers (or yourself, for that matter) to keep the date clean. You can enforce this with a check constraint: `CHECK (END_DATE = TRUNC(END_DATE))` and a similar one for `START_DATE`.

Comment: I attempted to run the query this way but still got the same error:
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @user1909680 Can you edit your original post with the table structures and some sample data?

Comment: @user1909680 This query is working -- see this sql fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ec0a/3. It just does not include the `where` clause but when I ran it in TOAD it worked without any errors. Is this the full query you are running?

Comment: Yes. This is the full query I am running. I saw the sql fiddle but my aim is to display the total of the total column displayed in the sql fiddle. So I need the display the sum of the two total values

Comment: Ok, can you edit your original post with the desired result of your sample data? do you want a total row?

Comment: @bluefeet I have provided sample output of the query

Comment: @user1909680 Do you want it as a column or as a row?  The row can easily be done using `group by rollup`?

Comment: @bluefeet Preferably a row if possible.

Comment: @bluefeet how would i do this as a column?

Comment: @user1909680 If you wanted a column, then I would use a common table expression for the subquery see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ec0a/14

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure where in your schema the various attributes are, try this:

```
SELECT z.BOOKING_ID, r.ROOM_NO , SUM(TOTAL) TOTAL 
FROM  (SELECT ri.room_No, dt.Booking_id,
             (END_DATE-START_DATE) DAYDIFF, 
             ((END_DATE-START_DATE)*ROOM_PRICE) TOTAL 
       FROM ROOM_TBL ri
             NATURAL JOIN ROOM_DETAILS_TBL dt
       WHERE BOOKING_ID = &BOOKING_ID) z 
   Join ROOM_TBL r  
     On r.ROOM_NO = z.Room_No
```